# Excel:Handle exception for workbook.open

Tags: c#, excel

How to handle exception in "C#" for the errors like->

```
Code:
Workbooks.Open(folderPath,filename,Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,"",""....)

"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070BBC): Office has detected a problem with this file. To help protect your computer this file cannot be opened.
at Excel.Workbooks.Open"
```

Few excels work without error,but few throw above error.
Please suggest some answers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to open Excel file:

```
    String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
    // Create connection object by using the preceding connection string.
    OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    // Open connection with the database.
    objConn.Open();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I don`t think so this will work.How can we change data source  here?

Comment: yes it is difficult to change data source. but it is one of the solution that i suggest.